# Select Max value and bring other data from that row

Tags: sql, join, max

I am trying to find the seller with the most "ItemsSold" and display that seller and everything else in that row. For some reason, my query keeps pulling the whole table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Name,
   Username,
   Password,
   Address,
   Email,
   CCNumber,
   CCExpiration,
   ItemsSold
FROM auctionsite.dbo.Seller
JOIN (SELECT MAX(ItemsSold) AS id FROM auctionsite.dbo.Seller GROUP BY 
   ItemsSold) max ON id = max.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and logic to fetch one row:

```
select s.*
from auctionsite.dbo.Seller s
order by s.itemSold desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  if there are ties, then this fetches only one of the tied rows.

If you want all ties, one method uses a subquery:

```
select s.*
from auctionsite.dbo.Seller s
where s.itemSold = (select max(s2.itemSold) from auctionsite.dbo.Seller s2);
```